# It's not a shopping rec question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This question got closed as asking for shopping suggestions:

[USB-Ethernet adapter for a laptop without Ethernet socket](https://superuser.com/questions/1271094/usb-ethernet-adapter-for-a-laptop-without-ethernet-socket)

> Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

OP *is* asking whether a USB-Ethernet adapter will suit their needs in the same way as a laptop with an Ethernet port. Not that there's much else to say other than "yes this kind of adapter works as intended, it's not a made up fake dongle", I just think the question is not rightfully closed.

Comment: Question reworded (which the OP or you could have done) and reopened.

Comment: I don't think there was ever a problem with that phrasing but sure, I'm glad this was resolved

Comment: Well the original question said "I am looking to buy a new laptop" and "If I buy a laptop like this" - a clear indication of a shopping question.